# Update existing records relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a User resource with like 100 existing user records.

Each user has a relation with a Status table.

user.rb

```
has_one :status
```

status.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I need to create this association not only for new users, but also for existing ones.

How can I do that?
Also.. I'm using rails 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use console.

```
User.all.each |user|
  Status.create(user_id: user.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems the way to go, but when would I trigger a method with that logic if I don't want to do that from the console in prod?

Comment: There are few ways. You can add that code to the `status` migration or you could create a method that you have access to in production for example: like an admin view with a button that says "`add status to existing users`. but I would prob just use the console.

Comment: How would I do that from the migration file? Can I make a call to a method from the model after the up method?

Comment: If you have already created your Status model, you can create another migration and instead of add `add_column` etc. You would just drop in the code above. If you haven't already created the status model, you can add the code in the same file that u create the Status table in as long as it is below the creation `do` and `end` sections.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to generate a migration

```
rails g migration AddUserreferenceToStatus user:references
```

and check the generated migration file if table name is okay, then migrate it. and

then you can run @miler350 method to create status for the old users.